# How to define method for all parametric subtypes of an abstract type in Julia?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have an abstract base class:

```
abstract type B end
```

and many concrete subtypes:

```
struct C1{T,V} <: B end
struct C2{T,V} <: B end
...
```

how to define a method for all subtypes in an elegant way?

```
result_type(::C1{T,V}) = T
result_type(::C2{T,V}) = T
...
```

The `subtypes` function doesn't seem to contain the parameter types `T` and `V` that I am trying to query, is there a clean solution?

```
for C in subtypes(B)
    # how to define result_type for C?
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the type parameter to the abstract type.

```
abstract type B{T,V} end
struct C1{T,V} <: B{T,V} end
struct C2{T,V} <: B{T,V} end
result_type(::B{T,V}) where {T,V} = T
```

Comment: The code returns an error on Julia 0.6.2. I think the last method should be defined with `where` clause.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I was trying to do it without parameters on the base class, but I guess I will have to add the parameters to avoid boilerplate code.

Comment: Maybe a solution with metaprogramming? Adding the parameters to the base class lead to other issues down the line, like the inability to subtype as in `struct C{T,V} <: B end`